# JS clear input value that has been written to txt div

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing an application similar to that of a command prompt. It takes userCommand as input & writes the output to a txt id. Im wanting to have it clear the txt area when user submits command "Cls".

HTML:

```
<div class="Typewriter">
<txt id='output'></txt>
</div>

<input id='cmd' onfocus="clearThis()" size="25" style="font-size:14pt;"/>
<button onclick='text()'>Enter</button>
```

JS:

```
function clearThis(){
  if(cmd.value='Cls')
    document.getElementById('output').value='';
  }
}
```

I have searched high & low but none of the scripts ive found seem to do anything & I cant figure it out. Any help would be much appreciated! TIA

Comment: Your javascript syntax is invalid (you have no opening bracket for your if statement but have a closing one).  Also, `<txt>` is an invalid html element. Lastly, look at when you can calling the `clearThis()` function. I think you can to call it in the `onclick` event

Comment: Textarea replaces the output text with a solid blank box where as <txt> actually writes the input to the screen so a bit confused on that tbh. But I will try what you have said. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming in command if you write `cls` then it clean the output and in other cases it will write something in `output`

Html

```
<input id='cmd' size="25" style="font-size:14pt;"/>
<button onclick='performOperation()'>Enter</button>

<div class="Typewriter">
<txt id='output'></txt>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function performOperation(){
  if(cmd.value.toLowerCase()=='cls')
    document.getElementById('output').innerText ='';
  else
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += cmd.value + "<br/>";
}
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/d7vx4o19/1/)

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend, it works perfectly!

Comment: @Bl1xY - you can mark it answered if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try `<input type="text" id="output">` instead of `<txt id='output'></txt>`.